# Can we run our test suite on different browser by using selenium webdriver without using selenium grid?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have googled alot but unable to find the way?

I want to run my test suite on different browser without changing browsert name in excel or xml file.

Can somebody help me on it?

Comment: This might be useful
http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2013/02/passing-parameters-to-testcase-using.html

Comment: I really want to Thank you santosh. Your blog is really helpful. Now my question is how could we justify the test case on failing? like I have used TestNG and suppose my test cases fail. So I am unable to see the fail method for specific browser. It just display failed method. Please resolve it. If my question is not readable then let me know. Thanks

Comment: You are most welcome @TNJ. You've a hold of browser name in your testcase so it is easy to append browser name to your testcase failure message. (I've posted answer just go through it :))

Comment: I do not want to add in the message Because I will not check the console. I am saying about the testng report where my method fails. So How to append in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog might be useful.

http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2013/02/passing-parameters-to-testcase-using.html

**ExampleTestCase.java**

```
   public class ExampleTestCase   
   {  
     private static WebDriver driver;
     private String browserName;
     @Parameters({"browser,version"})
     @BeforeClass
     public void beforeClass(String browser,String version)
     {
          driver=getDriverInstance(browser,version);
          browserName=browser;
     }
     @BeforeTest
     public void beforeTest()
     {
     }  
     @Test
     public void f()
     {
          //your test code here
     }
    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest()
    {
        //along with your failure messages append browserName to know in which browser it has failed
        System.out.println("Test failed in "+browserName);
    }
    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass()
    {

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
   <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">  
   <suite thread-count="2" name=MyTestSuite" parallel="tests">  
       <test name="RunInFirefox" preserve-order="false">
          <parameter name="browser" value="firefox">
          <parameter name="version" value="8"/>
          <parameter name="profile" value="default">
                <classes preserve-order="true">  
                      <class name="com.test.TestCase1"/>  
                      <class name="com.test.TestCase2"/>  
                      <class name="com.test.TestCase3"/>  
                </classes>  
       </test>  
       <test name="RunInChrome" preserve-order="false">
          <parameter name="browser" value="chrome">
          <parameter name="version" value="21"/>  
               <classes preserve-order="true">  
                    <class name="com.test.TestCase1"/>  
                    <class name="com.test.TestCase2"/>  
                    <class name="com.test.TestCase3"/>  
               </classes>  
        </test>  
</suite>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JUnit you can do it with `@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)`:

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class StackoverflowTestNoGrid {
    private final WebDriver driver;

    public StackoverflowTestNoGrid(final WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> driverToTest() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { { new ChromeDriver() }, { new FirefoxDriver() } });
    }

    @Test
    public void titleTest() {
        this.driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");
        // ... do some stuff
        // ... assert smth
    }
}
```

In method that is annotated with `@Parameters` you can say witch parameters should be passed to constuctor. In this case ChromeDriver and FirefoxDriver.

Comment: Thanks. But I am using TestNG.:)

Answer (score 0):

I had an unusual set of requirements while integrating with our Jenkins server.

I put all of my tests in abstract classes and then created a class for each browser that I wanted to test with

TestChrome
TestFirefox
TestInternetExplorer

Then when the tests fail, you can see the browser as part of the class name within the relevant package.

This allowed me to use exclusion and inclusion rules to filter tests that I wanted to run with certain browsers into different Jenkins jobs optionally.  As IE testing is painfully slow, this allowed us to test our production environments with chrome to verify everything deployed properly.